# Loading metal kernel shaders for testing

Tags: ios, swift, macos, shader, metal

I'm trying to make a cocoa touch framework that will be performing some parallel computations on OSX/iOS and I'm having some issues with setting up the tests. Whenever I try to run :

```
library = device.newDefaultLibrary()!
```

I get hit by the error :

```
/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-55.2.8/Framework/MTLLibrary.mm:1016: failed assertion `filepath must not be nil.'
```

I was also trying to load shaders straight from the bundle without success.

How do I load up metal shaders properly so I can use them within a framework / tests?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you loading the shaders from the correct bundle for the tests? `NSBundle.mainBundle()` will not return a correct bundle for tests.

Comment: If you are trying to do this in a playground, the `newDefaultLibrary()` method will not work. you will need to create your own filepath like I explained in my [blog post](http://mhorga.org/2016/03/07/using-metalkit-part-8.html) not long ago.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a Metal library from your framework with this code:

```
let library = try! sceneKitView.device!.newLibraryWithFile(NSBundle(forClass: TheNameOfThisClass.self).URLForResource("default", withExtension: "metallib")!.path!)
```

BUT I filed rdar://22618641 in September 2015 with a sample project that demonstrates that you can’t load precompiled Metal libraries from frameworks — you get the same error you saw above when you try to use the library.

(Well, you CAN load the library, you just can’t actually use it.)